# Remove extra spaces from all cells in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, multiple-columns

I have this function:

```
def Remove_Space(string):

    return string.rstrip().lstrip()
```

And I would like to run this on each cell in a dataframe so that if a value has spaces before or after the letters of the string they are dropped. What is a good way to iterate through the columns list and map these values.

The end goal would be to have a dataframe in which all of the values for each column do not have spaces before and after the strings.

I was thinking something along the lines of....

```
for i in df.columns:

    valueDict=dict(zip(df[i], [Remove_Space(x) for x in df[i]])

df.replace(valueDict)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip())
```

If there are integers or floats and you want to convert the ints/flaots to string, then use this:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).strip())
```

Or to keep the values as ints/floats:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

Comment: What if there are some columns that are interger or float. Then this would throw an error sign, right? Is there a way to do it so that it takes that into account?

Comment: I have updated the answer with 2 options in case of integer or float in the df. If this answer your question, remember to mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you may `stack` all columns into series and do `str.strip` and `unstack` back

Sample data(*notice all values are misaligned because of spaces in front and behind them*):

```
Out[187]:
      0        1           2
0  one      two   three
1    AA  BB               CC


df.stack().str.strip().unstack()

Out[186]:
     0    1      2
0  one  two  three
1   AA   BB     CC
```

---

Or, you may use dict comprehension to `strip` each column and reconstruct new `df`

```
pd.DataFrame({col: df[col].str.strip() for col in df})

Out[188]:
     0    1      2
0  one  two  three
1   AA   BB     CC
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"c1":['  hello',"andy "],"c2":["Bye ","Lily"]})
df2 = df.applymap(str.strip)
print(df2.c1[0])
'hello'
```